# Match variables between two excel files

Tags: excel

I have two datasets containing occupations names and their description in excel:

[image: Occupation: Chief executives, Legislators...]

I want to create a new dataset with all occupations that match between both datasets.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers ***write their own code*** and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. If you have a particular issue after [researching](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) existing answers, please [edit] your post to share some background info and a **[mcve] of your code** and relevant data. See the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) and find more tips here: *"[ask]"* and in the [help/on-topic], as well as this [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the sites' top user. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using a VLookup.

1. For ease, have all three datasets within the same spreadsheet, if you can, if not doesn't matter, but have them open.
2. Copy all the Occupations (not descriptions) from DataSet1 into Dataset 3.
3. Enter the formula below in dataset3 under the occupation description header.

   - Occupation = cell of the occupation in dataset 3.
   - Dataset2 Range = Enter the range of the searchable content ensuring the occupations are the left most(First selected).
4. Drag the formula down
5. Select All and insert as Table and filter out on "No Match").

Formula example:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Occupation,Dataset2 Range,2,FALSE),"No Match")`